# Creating a 'jsconfig.json' file for Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to Visual Studio Code and have been following a tutorial to create Node.js applications with Visual Studio Code.

I need to create a *jsconfig.json* file, the tutorial informs me that there should be a green lightbulb in the status bar, which will generate the file when clicked on. Unfortunately, I cannot see it and I am pretty sure that it should be showing, considering there is no *jsconfig.json* file in the 'myExpressApp' folder. Please see the screenshot...

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? Also, do you mean `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I am following https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs#_adding-a-jsconfigjson-configuration-file

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, don't forget to upvote and accept them (or provide feedback if they aren't helpful). You'll also get a small rep bonus when you accept answers (+2).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a [Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) build, with recent versions of Visual Studio Code, if you are only using JavaScript, [a *jsconfig.json* file is no longer required](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15205). If none is provided, the root directory will be treated as an implicit JavaScript project.

If you are working with TypeScript, you still need a *tsconfig.json* file. See [Aurora0001's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40831596/306149) for creating this.

I'll update the Visual Studio Code documentation/tutorial to reflect this change.

Comment: I believe that I am on 1.7.2 recovery build. But not an insiders build.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that the lightbulb doesn't appear as expected, but you can still generate a *jsconfig.json* yourself. If you're planning to use TypeScript, you can just run this in your terminal (in the project directory):

```
tsc --init
```

This will create a *tsconfig.json* file ready for you (you'll need to then add `"allowJs": true` in that file, because that makes it [equivalent to `jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)).

You could also just click 'New File', copy in the contents from the tutorial and save. There shouldn't be any detrimental effect to your project by not clicking the lightbulb to do it.