# Is the jsconfig.json file required to be used in every JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-jsconfig

I am working with a JavaScript project. Is it is necessary (or recommended) to use the *jsconfig.json* file in every JavaScript project?

Will adding the *jsconfig.json* file make the development process easier, or is it only used for larger JavaScript projects?

I noticed that the *jsconfig.json* file has something to do with Visual Studio Code. How does it improve the developer experience with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This is an opinion based question, and is therefore off topic. Not only does the word "should" almost always denote an opinion based question, but this is a loaded topic in general, as some feel that a `jsconfig.json` file isn't worth using, and some feel it is. Personally, I think if your going to try and configure JS using a TSC based technology, why not just use TSC to transpile your code all together. But that's my opinion, which probably varies from other peoples.

Comment: I have changed the title to be less opinion-based.

Comment: Your question needs to offer an elementary reproducible example. I can't reproduce this problem. The reason why it isn't reproducible is because its not a problem, no one ever failed to execute a program because of a lack of JSConfig.json file being present in their codebase. For this question to be valid, you would need to demonstrate an issue that would make someone think that they would need a `JSConfig.json` file.

Comment: Although, even if you could, which I doubt you could, it would still not be a valid question because it would probably be flag`able as a typo or a mistake by the author.

Comment: In an attempt to not just be negative, and bash on you. Which is not what I am trying to do  (I really just want stack overflow to be the great resource it has always been) I will tell you that perhaps a better question, though check to make sure it isn't a dup, because most likley it will be, is the following: ___"What does a `jsconfig.json` file do? What benifits come from using one?"___

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416736/knowing-when-to-flag-and-knowing-when-i-am-being-overly-critical).

Comment: Related: *[What is jsconfig.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68675994/)* and *[Creating a 'jsconfig.json' file for Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831068/)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen You may close this question as a duplicate if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a supplement, I’d like to say that in the official document. The *LANGUAGES-JavaScript-JavaScript* projects (file *jsconfig.json*) explains when we need this file.

The *LANGUAGES-NODE.JS/JAVASCRIPT-Working with JavaScript* explains its function, the parts of it, and some examples of writing this file, how to use a JavaScript support and so on.

You can refer to this: *[Working with JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript)*

Comment: Where is "LANGUAGES-JavaScript-JavaScript" located? Inside a configuration file? On a web page (GitHub?). Something else? Where is "the official document"? What official document? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71554194/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).